# ZMQ Dealer sends and receives messages to itself

Tags: c++, zeromq

I have a zmq dealer socket that I'm connecting to a port on my machine that no one else is connected to. I use the ZMQ_IMMEDIATE option that stops the socket from sending a message with no connected peer. If I try to send a message enough times (about five minutes), eventually I'm able to send the message and receive a message with the size and data I was attempting to send.

Using zmq_socket_monitor shows eventually that the dealer socket is able to connect and send/receive a message to/from itself. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
static int read_msg(void* s, zmq_event_t* event, char* ep)
{
 int rc ;
 zmq_msg_t msg1; // binary part
 zmq_msg_init (&msg1);
 zmq_msg_t msg2; // address part
 zmq_msg_init (&msg2);
 rc = zmq_msg_recv (&msg1, s, 0);
 if (rc == -1 && zmq_errno() == ETERM)
 return 1 ;
 assert (rc != -1);
 assert (zmq_msg_more(&msg1) != 0);
 rc = zmq_msg_recv (&msg2, s, 0);
 if (rc == -1 && zmq_errno() == ETERM)
 return 1;
 assert (rc != -1);
 assert (zmq_msg_more(&msg2) == 0);
 // copy binary data to event struct
 const char* data = (char*)zmq_msg_data(&msg1);
 memcpy(&(event->event), data, sizeof(event->event));
 memcpy(&(event->value), data+sizeof(event->event), sizeof(event->value));
 // copy address part
 const size_t len = zmq_msg_size(&msg2) ;
 ep = (char*)memcpy(ep, zmq_msg_data(&msg2), len);
 *(ep + len) = 0 ;
 return 0 ;
}


// dealer socket monitor thread
static void *dealer_socket_monitor (void *ctx)
{
 zmq_event_t event;
 static char addr[1025] ;
 int rc;

 printf("starting monitor...\n");

 void *s = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
 assert (s);
 int num = 0;
 rc = zmq_connect (s, "inproc://monitor.dealer");
 assert (rc == 0);
 while (!read_msg(s, &event, addr)) {
 switch (event.event) {
 case ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED:
 printf (" DEALER connect retried socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER connect retried socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED:
 printf (" DEALER connect delayed socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER connect delayed socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_LISTENING:
 printf (" DEALER listening socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER listening socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED:
 printf (" DEALER connected socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER connected socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_MONITOR_STOPPED:
 printf (" DEALER monitor ending socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER monitor ending socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPTED:
 printf (" DEALER accepted socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER accepted socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSE_FAILED:
 printf (" DEALER socket close failure error code %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSED:
 printf (" DEALER closed socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER closed socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 case ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
 printf (" DEALER disconnected socket descriptor %d %d\n", event.value, num);
 printf (" DEALER disconnected socket address %s\n", addr);
 break;
 default:
 printf(" DEALER default case\n");
 }
 }
 zmq_close (s);
 return NULL;
}
int main() {
     pthread_t thread ;
    std::string connect = "tcp://localhost:49150";
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t client (context, ZMQ_DEALER);
    int m_linger = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int m_timeoutMs = 1000;
    int imm = 1;
    // release the socket / port asa it disconnects
    client.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &m_linger, sizeof(m_linger));
    client.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &m_timeoutMs, sizeof(m_timeoutMs));
    client.setsockopt(ZMQ_SNDTIMEO, &m_timeoutMs, sizeof(m_timeoutMs));
    client.setsockopt(ZMQ_IMMEDIATE, &imm, sizeof(imm));

    client.connect(connect.c_str());
    std::cout << "Connecting client to " << connect << std::endl;

     // socket monitoring
    int rc = zmq_socket_monitor ((void*)client, "inproc://monitor.dealer", ZMQ_EVENT_ALL);
    rc = pthread_create (&thread, NULL, dealer_socket_monitor, (void*)context);
    int more = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        zmq::message_t blank{};
        zmq::message_t message(sizeof(int));
        zmq::message_t response;
        int more; //  Multipart detection
        std::cout << "Client no linger sending message more enabled" << std::endl;
        auto ret = client.send(blank, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        if (!ret)
        {
            std::cout << "timeout on send, trying again" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "Client no linger sending message more disabled" << std::endl;
        ret = client.send(message);
        if (!ret)
        {
            std::cout << "timeout on send second, trying again";
            continue;
        }
        ret = client.recv(&response);
        size_t more_size = sizeof (more);
        client.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
        while (more)
        {
            std::cout << "Client received message with more coming. Size of message " << response.size() << std::endl;
            client.recv(&response);
            client.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
        }
        std::cout << "Client received final part of message. Size of message " << response.size() << " message " << *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(message.data())) << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Notice that the size of the message is the size of an int, what I initialized the zmq message with. Looking at the program I have that originally created this error, the message contains the same data that was attempted to be sent out.
End of the output I get from running the program:

```
 DEALER closed socket descriptor 10 0
 DEALER closed socket address tcp://localhost:49150
 DEALER connect retried socket descriptor 185 0
 DEALER connect retried socket address tcp://localhost:49150
 DEALER connect delayed socket descriptor 115 0
 DEALER connect delayed socket address tcp://localhost:49150
 DEALER connected socket descriptor 10 0
 DEALER connected socket address tcp://localhost:49150
Client no linger sending message more disabled
Client received message with more coming. Size of message 0
Client received final part of message. Size of message 4 message 0
```

Compiled with: g++ -std=c++11 client.cpp -o client -g -lzmq -lpthread by GCC 6.3
cppzmq-devel 4.1.4-6 and zmq 4.1.4-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2927) with NodeJS where a socket would eventually connect to itself. It seems the same is happening here: the ZeroMQ socket creates a local ephemeral port that is the same as the port you are connecting to (49150).

If so, it should not happen when you connect to a reserved port (< 1024) where no service is listening, such as port 7. Binding/listening to a port outside the ephemeral port range (< 32768 on Linux) should solve the issue.

Use tools such use `netstat` or `tcpdump`/`wireshark` to vetify that this is actually happening on the socket/network level.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have edited my post to be more like an answer instead of a comment. I am pretty sure this is the actual issue.

Comment: My teammate found the same problem that a dealer channel would connect to itself at variable time intervals between 10 minutes or more, the ports range used were in the range of 51xxx, after reading this answer, he changed the port range to 21xxx, and no longer has the problem, he sends his thanks. He would have commented himself but the StackOverflow point system prevents him from commenting.